# c++ Template not identifying type double

Tags: c++, templates, double

I have just studied c++ templates and it was great that the books example compiled and worked.  Then in the exercises at the end of the chapter I tried my own template programme.  The code simple passes an array to the template function and it determines the largest value in the array.  The problem is that when the type double array is passed the template is treating it as type int and displaying 5 as the larges value and not 5.0.

Here is my code

```
// Exercise 5.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
T max5(const T array[]);

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;

    int intA[5]{ 1, 2, 5, 4, 3 };
    double doubleA[5]{ 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0 };

    cout << "Max int " << max5(intA) << endl;
    cout << "Max double " << max5(doubleA) << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
T max5(const T array[])
{
    T max = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];

        //std::cout << "Max: " << max << std::endl;
    }

    return max;
}
```

Any ideas as to why?

Regards

Mickydint

Comment: What happens when you just output `cout << 5.0`?

Comment: One issue that I'm seeing immediately is that you need to set the precision and showpoint.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/showpoint/

The other issue that I see currently is that you're templatizing the displaying of data via cout, which is going to cause complications between integers and doubles.  I suppose you want whole, not decimal-point-showing numbers on integral types, and precise numbers on non-integral types.  Templates don't really shine their awesomeness in this regard.

Comment: When I try to cout << 5.0; it just displays 5.

Comment: what error did you get? i have no problem with your codes except i have to insert an = after intA[5] and doubleA[5].

Comment: @Zulukas Thanks Zulukas using those two commands sorted it.  I'm returning to  C++ after many years break, I would have thought displaying a double would automatically have a precision to show the decimal portion as that is the point of them.  But it does not (at least if the decimal portion is zero), and the problem is solved.  Yay.

Comment: @Shiping No errors Shiping, just the double is displayed as an int.  The non use of the = sign is I believe a C++ 11 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the correct types back, the problem is with you displaying them.

```
cout << "int == "    << typeid(max5(intA)).name()    << endl;
cout << "double == " << typeid(max5(doubleA)).name() << endl;
```

`std::cout` has different ways of showing higher precision or different formatting.

Like:

[std::setprecision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)
[std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)
std::scientific
std::hexfloat
std::defaultfloat

and [std::showpoint](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/showpoint) as Zulukas already pointed out.

```
// Exercise 5.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
T max5(const T array[]);

int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;

    int intA[5]{ 1, 2, 5, 4, 3 };
    double doubleA[5]{ 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.0 };

    cout << "int == "    << typeid(max5(intA)).name()    << endl;
    cout << "double == " << typeid(max5(doubleA)).name() << endl;

    cout << std::showpoint;
    cout << "Max int "    << max5(intA) << endl;
    cout << "Max double " << max5(doubleA) << endl;
    cout << std::noshowpoint;

    cout << std::fixed;
    cout << "Max int "    << max5(intA)    << endl;
    cout << "Max double " << max5(doubleA) << endl;

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

template <typename T>
T max5(const T array[])
{
    T max = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] > max) max = array[i];

        //std::cout << "Max: " << max << std::endl;
    }

    return max;
}
```

[Live](http://ideone.com/xwyPvo)